# Symfony2 UniqueEntity constraint SQL error instead of message

Tags: php, validation, symfony, unique

I'm stuck with creating a user registration form with Symfony2.
I'm trying to define an Unique constraint on the `email` attribute of my `User` class.

Acme\APPBundle\Entity\User.php

```
namespace Acme\APPBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\APPBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
* @ORM\Table("users")
* @UniqueEntity(
*       fields={"email"},
*       message="email already used"
* )
*/
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    protected $email;


    [...]
}
```

Acme\APPBundle\Form\Type\UserType.php

```
namespace Acme\APPBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('email', 'email');
        $builder->add('password', 'repeated', array(
            'first_name' => 'password',
            'second_name' => 'confirm',
            'type' => 'password',
        ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\APPBundle\Entity\User',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
}
```

I've added the constraint following the documentation but I still get an exception like :

```
An exception occured while executing 'INSERT INTO users ( ... )'
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
```

It looks like my `message` value defined in annotations is ignored and the form validation is bypassed since it should fail before attempting to insert row in database.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong ?

---

EDIT :

Following  Matteo 'Ingannatore' G.'s advice I've noticed that my form is not properly validated.
I forgot to mention that I use a registration class that extends the user form. I've written my code after what is explained in the [Symfony Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html).

Thus I have :

Acme\APPBundle\Form\Model\Registration.php

```
namespace Acme\APPBundle\Form\Model;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

use Acme\APPBundle\Entity\User;

class Registration
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Type(type="Acme\APPBundle\Entity\User")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\True()
     */
    protected $termsAccepted;

    public function setUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function getTermsAccepted()
    {
        return $this->termsAccepted;
    }

    public function setTermsAccepted($termsAccepted)
    {
        $this->termsAccepted = (Boolean) $termsAccepted;
    }
}
```

Acme\APPBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationType.php

```
namespace Acme\APPBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('user', new UserType());
        $builder->add('terms', 'checkbox', array('property_path' => 'termsAccepted'));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'registration';
    }
}
```

Acme\APPBundle\Controller\AccountController.php

```
namespace Acme\APPBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

use Acme\AccountBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationType;
use Acme\AccountBundle\Form\Model\Registration;

class AccountController extends Controller
{
    public function registerAction()
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new RegistrationType(), new Registration());

        return $this->render('AcmeAPPBundle:Account:register.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }



    public function createAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        $form = $this->createForm(new RegistrationType(), new Registration());

        $form->handleRequest($this->getRequest());

        if ($form->isValid()) { // FIXME !!
            $registration = $form->getData();

            $em->persist($registration->getUser());
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('home'));
        }

        return $this->render('AcmeAPPBundle:Account:register.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }

}
```

I guess the error I get might be caused by the fact that the `Registration` Form is validated, but the `User` Form within isn't submitted to validation. Am I wrong ?
How can I simply change that behaviour ? I saw there is a `cascade_validation` option but it seems to be useless here.
I think it's strange that Symfony Cookbook provides both guides to create a user provider and create a registration form but does not explain how to get those work along.

Comment: Have you double-checked if the entity validation is really called? Also check that there are no duplicates inside the table.

Comment: make sure you have mapping only defined as annotation if you have doctrine folder in 'bundle/resources/config' then rename it

Comment: [X] There are no duplicates inside the table
[X] Mapping is only defined as annotation
[  ] Not sure that entity validation is called. I'm editing my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found what the acutal problem was.
The validation was processed only on the `RegistrationType` instance but not on the `UserType` within.

To make sure that the validation also checks the constraints for the user I added the following code to my `RegistrationType` class :

```
public function setDefaultOptions(Options ResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\APPBundle\Form\Model\Registration',
        'cascade_validation' => true,
    ));
}
```

What changes everything is the `cascade_validation` option that must be set to `true` for this class while this option is set on the `UserType` class in the CookBook example.

Also, don't forget to :

```
use Symfony\Component\OptionResolver\OptionsResolverInterface
```

in the file where you define the `setDefaultOptions`.